# Why is Bug_Project not a suitable table name in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to build a database in oracle and I am stuck creating a link table between Bug and Project. I think I have done most of it but when trying to execute the code for the link table it comes back with the following error:
ORA-00903: invalid table name

My code is below (obviously not finished yet):

```
CREATE TABLE Project
(
    ProjID varchar(5),
    ProjName varchar(10),
    ProjStartDate date,
    primary key (ProjID)
)
-- this is creating a table called Bug that has 4 variables, BugID being the primary key 
CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    BugID varchar(5),
    BugType varchar(10),
    BugDesc varchar(10),
    BugTime timestamp(3),
    primary key(BugID)
)

CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    BugID varchar(5),
    ProjID varchar(5),
    primary key(BugID, ProjID),
    foreign key(BugID) references(Bug)
    foreign key(ProjID) references(Project)
)
COMMIT;

DROP TABLE Bug;
DROP TABLE Project;

COMMIT;
```

Any help anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated!

The full error message is here:

Error starting at line : 23 in command -

```
CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    BugID varchar(5),
    ProjID varchar(5),
    primary key(BugID, ProjID),
    foreign key(BugID) references(Bug)
    foreign key(ProjID) references(Project)
)
```

Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:
*Action:

UPDATE: I have also tried putting in commas in areas like after `references(Bug)` but still no luck

Comment: foreign key(BugID) references(Bug) ,
    foreign key(ProjID) references(Project)  you forgot comma

Comment: Also, tables have _columns_, not variables.

Comment: @Andrew I have already tried that, it did not work for me.

Comment: Use integer instead of varchar for the id columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the referenced columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    BugID varchar(5),
    ProjID varchar(5),
    primary key(BugID, ProjID),
    foreign key(BugID) references Bug (bugid), --<< don't forget the comma
    foreign key(ProjID) references  Project (projectid)
);
```

Alternatively you can just reference the table, but then you need to remove the parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    BugID varchar(5),
    ProjID varchar(5),
    primary key(BugID, ProjID),
    foreign key(BugID) references bug, --<< no parentheses
    foreign key(ProjID) references project
);
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, but: `number` is probably a better data type for an "ID" column.